# Sending POST request using http url connection java

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection, serversocket

I'm trying to configure a system client-server.
The server uses a java server socket, and the client uses and http url connection to connect to the server.

The code of the server is:

```
private static ServerSocket server;
private static int port = 9876;
server = new ServerSocket(port);
while(true){
    System.out.println("Waiting for the client request");
    Socket socket = server.accept();
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

    Object object = objectInputStream.readObject();
    if (object instanceof String) {
        String payload = (String) object;
        System.out.println("Payload received from client: " + payload);
    }
socket.close();
```

The code of the client is:

```
int serverPort = 9876;
String serverURL = "http://localhost:" + serverPort;
Object payload = "Test payload";
HttpURLConnection connection = null;

try {
    URL url = new URL(serverURL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

    objectOutputStream.writeObject(payload);
    objectOutputStream.flush();
    objectOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (connection != null) {
        connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

The error returned by the system is: java.io.EOFException in this line:
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream).
What could be the probelm?
Thank you for your time!

I tried to use different functions to read the stream, but I need to use the class ObjectInputStream.
Using that, it doesn't work.

Comment: (1) Why does your client want to use the `http` protocol to connect to your server? (2) Does your server use the Http protocol? (3) I don't see any http implementation on your server. (4) Please stop using the http protocol to connect to your server. (5) The easiest way to test your server is to open a terminal and execute the command `telnet 127.0.0.1 9876`.

Comment: if you want write a simple http server yourself, you can reference this `Create a Simple Web Server in Java (1) - HTTP Server`(https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1040097/Create-a-Simple-Web-Server-in-Java-HTTP-Server)